# Passing a variable to javascript function from codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, function

i bascially want to get the value of a variable from the codebehind to use in a javascript function for autocomplete....here is the function:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
$('.PONumbers').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({                        
                url: "../GenericHandlers/PONumber.ashx",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term,
                    userid:'622'
                },                        
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3
    })

  }).unbind("blur.autocomplete"); 

 $("body:not(.ui-autocomplete)").live('click', function(){
        $('.PONumbers').autocomplete("close");
    });
```

Where i have the value '622' is where i want the value from the codebehind....any suggstions?

Comment: what language do you use for your code-behind?

Comment: If this value is required for the request, I believe you should make this value available at client side (even if you have to put it in a hidden field or something), so you can easily pass the value as request data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exposing a property in the code-behind, and you should be able to access the value like this:

```
userid:'<%= this.UserID %>'
```

And in the code-behind:

```
public int UserID
{
    get
    {
        return (int)Session["UserID"];
    }
}
```

**Using Page Methods**

You could probably leverage `PageMethods` for this too:

```
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
public static string GetLabelText()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

And on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    insertLabelData = function() {
        PageMethods.GetLabelText(onSuccess, onFailure);
    } 
    onSuccess = function(result) {
        var lbl = document.getElementById('lbl');
        lbl.innerHTML = result; //your code-behind value
    } 
    onFailure = function(error) {
        alert(error);
    } 
</script>
```

Here's the article I took the above code from: 
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/04/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods.aspx

And here is another tutorial on `PageMethods`:
http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX

Comment: you mean just declare nd inititalise the variable, yes?

Comment: Just create a property in the code-behind that returns the value you need, which in this case would be the `UserID`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the user ID as custom html properties in your ui-autocomplete tag. Then read from it.

```
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete" userid="<%=userID%>">
```

Then your Javascript you can get this attr:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").attr('userid') // will return the id printed in your input attr
```

Comment: not sure what you mean here, not really that familiar with javascript

Comment: I have added a example for you. This is the easiest way to do, because you don't need to change dynamic your JS file.